How to make Typescript derive that the same property of one type is the same type
I'm trying to sort items: Item[] having properties of type 'string' or 'number' without mixing types for each property:
type Item = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
  prop3: string;
  prop4: number;
}

I want to make it abstract, which property I'm sorting by, so i got: propertyName: keyof Item
I get property values in my sorting function this way:
items.sort((item1, item2) => {
  const value1 = item1[propertyName];
  const value2 = item2[propertyName];
...

so value1 is string | number, value2 is string | number too.
I want to use separate further logic for sorting by properties of type 'string' and by properties of type 'number', so I need to know the type of the property I'm sorting by. The problem is that TS doesn't get that the same property for any item is of the same type, so if value1 is a string - value2 either.
I'm trying to find out the most elegant way of types checking without unneeded checks for values, which would preferably be based on the type Item itself, not the values, like: 'if the type of property (propertyName) in Item is 'string' then ...'
Thanks for your help.

TypeScript just isn't able to do the type analysis you're describing here; it's close to ms/TS#30581, except the union string | number isn't a discriminated union so there's no simple non-redundant solution that the compiler can verify as type safe. You'll need at least one type assertion somewhere, probably two. For example, this playground link shows one way to do it. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Thanks for your answer, jcalz. Thus, 2 type checks/assertions won't be enough, cause for TS there 2 more cases are left uncovered: when the values are of different type. This leads to redundant conditional case which should never work.

Yes, that's right. Should I write up an answer?

I'm trying to explore what you are trying to implement, take a look at this playground here

type PickPropsByType<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type Item = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
  prop3: string;
  prop4: number;
};

type StringOnlyItem = PickPropsByType<Item, string>;
// StringOnlyItem is { prop1: string; prop3: string; }

type NumberOnlyItem = PickPropsByType<Item, number>;
// NumberOnlyItem is { prop2: number; prop4: number; }

const items: Item[] = [
    {
        prop1: "1prop1",
        prop2: 1,
        prop3: "1prop3",
        prop4: 2
    },
    {
        prop1: "2prop1",
        prop2: 3,
        prop3: "2prop3",
        prop4: 4
    },
    {
        prop1: "3prop1",
        prop2: 5,
        prop3: "3prop3",
        prop4: 6
    }
]

const propertyNameProp1: keyof Item = "prop1"; 
const propertyNameProp2: keyof Item = "prop2"; 

let propertyName: keyof Item;
let propertyOnlyString: StringOnlyItem;
let propertyOnlyNumber: NumberOnlyItem;



items.sort((item1, item2) => {

    // Explicit prop1
    const value1Prop1 = item1[propertyNameProp1]; //type of value1 === "string"
    const value2Prop1 = item2[propertyNameProp1]; //type of value1 === "string"


    // Explicit prop2
    const value1Prop2 = item1[propertyNameProp2]; //type of value2 === "number"
    const value2Prop2 = item2[propertyNameProp2]; //type of value2 === "number"


    // Type that pick only string properties from the Item 
    const value1String = item1[propertyOnlyString];
    const value2String = item2[propertyOnlyString];

    // Type that pick only numbers properties from the Item 
    const value1Number = item1[propertyOnlyNumber];
    const value2Number = item2[propertyOnlyNumber];


    // keyof Item, which need to be narrow
    const valueGeneric = item1[propertyName] //type of valueGeneric: string | number

    switch (propertyName) {
        case "prop1":
            const value1 = item1[propertyName]; //type of value1 === "string"
            const value2 = item2[propertyName]; //type of value2 === "string"
            break;

        case "prop2":
            const value1 = item1[propertyName]; //type of value1 === "number"
            const value2 = item2[propertyName]; //type of value2 === "number"
            break;

        case "prop3":
            const value1 = item1[propertyName]; //type of value1 === "string"
            const value2 = item2[propertyName]; //type of value2 === "string"
            break;

        case "prop4":
            const value1 = item1[propertyName]; //type of value1 === "number"
            const value2 = item2[propertyName]; //type of value2 === "number"
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }


    return 1;
});

In order to understand the type properly, if the propertyName value its not known at compile time, you need to make some narrowing, which means checking the types at runtime.

Thanks. Looks more complicated than processing 4 cases of possible value1/value2 combinations:

string/string
string/number
number/string
number/number

What I'm trying to do is to avoid cases 2 and 3 (which should never take place for certain reasons) and to check only once whether current property is of type 'string' or it's a number.

Let's create a util function that returns value when providing property. Example:
function pickBy<T, K extends keyof T>(item: T, property: K): T[K] {
    return item[property];
}

Now, in the sort function, you can use pickBy to get a sort value:
items.sort((item1, item2) => {
    const propertyName1 = 'prop1';
    const propertyName2 = 'prop2';

    const value1 = pickBy(item1, propertyName1);
    //    ^? string

    const value2 = pickBy(item2, propertyName2);
    //    ^? number

    return -1;
});


Unfortunately, this works the same way as my initial code. I get string | number values in the output of pickBy.
